# SQL Self Join without double cross results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm searching for the solution since hours, but cat get it.

My table:

```
ID         name          value1      value2
1          Meyer         20          _
2          Schmitt       20          _
3          Berger        _           20
4          Chief         _           20
```

my query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.name AS nameA, B.name AS nameB, A.value1 
FROM table AS A INNER JOIN table AS B
ON A.value1 = B.value2
```

result:

```
ID      nameA      nameB       value1
1       Meyer      Berger      20
1       Meyer      Chief       20
2       Schmitt    Berger      20
2       Schmitt    Chief       20
```

This should look like:

```
ID      nameA       nameB      value1
1       Meyer       Berger     20
2       Schmitt     Chief      20
```

**How can I get this result?**

I also tried the GROUP BY A.name, but get the wrong result:

```
ID       nameA      nameB     value1
1        Meyer      Berger    20
2        Schmitt    Berger    20
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  You should probably read up on database normalization.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're relating the records. If all the values of `value1` and `value2` are 20, how do you decide that "Meyer" belongs only with "Berger" and "Schmitt" belongs only with "Chief"?

Comment: You're going to need some other criteria to make this work. For example, why should the query only return Meyer Berger but not Meyer Chief?

Comment: You can't get your desired results with this table/data/structure. There's no way for the db to know that you want Meyer/Berger only, and not Meyer/Chief.

Comment: Hej! Thank you first! I cant and dont have to decide which name belongs to which name. I dont care about the pairing i just want that every name is just once there. So Meyer-Berger, Schmitt-Chief is as good as Meyer-Chief, Schmitt-Berger for me. Sorry for not mention that before. I just dont want to pair one name twice! Any ideas?

Comment: I just dont want to pair one name twice AND also not zero times.

Comment: Then you don't want to be using a database for this.  What you're asking for isn't idempotent or easily-expressible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified DBMS. This is tested in SQL Server:

```
with C as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by value1 order by ID) as rn1,
         row_number() over(partition by value2 order by ID) as rn2
  from YourTable
)
select A.ID, 
       A.name as nameA, 
       B.name as nameB, 
       A.value1  
from C as A
  inner join C as B
    on A.value1 = B.value2 and
       A.rn1 = B.rn2
```

Testable sample:

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  name varchar(10),
  value1 int,
  value2 int
)
insert into @T values
(1,          'Meyer',         20,          null),
(2,          'Schmitt',       20,          null),
(3,          'Berger',        null,        20),
(4,          'Chief',         null,        20)

;with C as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by value1 order by ID) as rn1,
         row_number() over(partition by value2 order by ID) as rn2
  from @T
)
select A.ID, 
       A.name as nameA, 
       B.name as nameB, 
       A.value1  
from C as A
  inner join C as B
    on A.value1 = B.value2 and
       A.rn1 = B.rn2
```

Comment: Hej! Thank you first. It looks like a solution, but sorry I'm just working with sqlite! Also possible there? I have never seen WITH C AS (...) Can you please explain it to me? Also possible in sqlite?

Comment: @airfrank - `with c as` is a common table expression. Don't know if that is available in sqlite. If not you should be able to use two sub-queries instead. You also need the ranking function row_number() and since I don't know anything about sqlite I can't tell you if that is en option for you.

Comment: Thank you! Your tip with the row_number got me to the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

According to this join criteria `A.value1 = B.value2` and your input table, Meyer is related to both Berger and Chief, and Schmitt is related to both Berger and Chief.  So a suspect there is more to the criteria/business rules of how these are related that you are not telling us.  **It looks like you are just using value1 and value2 as some funky foreign keys.  It is not clear why you think that Meyer wouldn't be related to Chief, or why Schmitt wouldn't be related to Berger.**

```
ID         name          value1      value2
1          Meyer         20          _
2          Schmitt       20          _
3          Berger        _           20
4          Chief         _           20
```

So it's not a problem with your query, but a problem with your data structure, **so let's fix value1 and value2**:

```
ID         name          value1      value2
1          Meyer         10          _
2          Schmitt       20          _
3          Berger        _           10
4          Chief         _           20
```

Now you will get the correct results.  But a more traditional design would look like this:

```
PersonId   PersonName    BossPersonId
1          Meyer         3
2          Schmitt       4
3          Berger        _
4          Chief         _
```

With this query:

```
Select A.Id, A.PersonName, B.PersonName as BossName
FROM table AS A INNER JOIN table AS B
ON A.BossPersonId= B.PersonId
```

Comment: Hej! Thank you first! I dont care about the pairing! I just want that nothing is paired twice. As explained in the comment above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it right now.

TABLE:

```
ID       name         value1         value2
1        Meyer        20             _
2        Muster       10             _
3        Heinz        20             _
4        Karl         _              20
5        Max          _              20
6        Zack         _              10
```

Split it in temp tables and order it by value

TABLE A:

```
ID       name        value1        value2
1        Muster      10            _
2        Meyer       20            _
3        Heinz       20            _
```

TABLE B:

```
ID       name        value1        value2
1        Zack        _             10
2        Karl        _             20
3        Max         _             20
```

and then join on A.ID=B.ID AND A.value1=B.value2

Post with rownumber helped me a lot, thx
best regards